# View more than 1000 rows in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

How can I view more than 1000 rows Rstudio because the view command show me only 1000 rows instead of 103400 in my data file.

`library(foreign) 
stata <- read.dta("/Users/cool/Desktop/LFS2010-12.dta", convert.factors= F, convert.underscore=T,
missing.type=T, warn.missing.labels = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

RStudio is limiting to 1000 rows with View(), to avoid poor performance opening large datasets.  If you want to see more, or different sets of rows in your data, perhaps the best way is to look at it in the console (i.e. mydata[10000:20000,]) or write the data to a csv file and view it there if you want a spreadsheet format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more recent or has always been there, but in RStudio 0.98.1091 with R 3.1.2 I was able to use `utils::View()` to launch an external viewer that wasn't limited to 1000 rows.  With your sample above, it would be:

```
utils::View(stata)
```

I just used this to view more than 10,000 rows in a data.frame.  I don't know what the upper limit is, if any, and the documentation doesn't mention an upper limit in any obvious way.